# Is this compost appropriate for transplanting/repotting tomatoes?

Tags: vegetables, compost, tomatoes

I have planted some tomato seeds (that came in a grow bag) in a flat planting tray and as the stems and leaves are growing up, I'm being convinced that I should move them back to the grow bags that are larger and do need more soil.

I've got this compost which is for flowers, but I was wondering if I could use it for my tomatoes.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not compost. It's coir, which is shredded coconut husk and some 20-20-20 fertilizer. The coir itself doesn't really have any nutrient value to it.

Your tomatoes will probably grow ok in it, but the fertilizer might have too much nitrogen which will encourage vegetative growth at the expense of fruiting. I think you'd be better off using real compost or [mixing your own potting soil](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/1483/51) and [supplementing with fertilizer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4098/51) as needed.

Comment: So what does one do with the coir? I've been looking for NPK 20-20-20 for ages and this one has it. Shall I mix it with my other flower's soil which should get 20-20-20 monthly?